# How do I turn 'a few days' into an adjective or otherwise modify a noun with it?

Tags: word-request

Is it 'a-few-day delays', or 'a few days delays', or something else? It's 'a seven-year-old son' but, using the same pattern, I couldn't find any matches for my guesses in Google News.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an adjective for this, but 'a delay of a few days' seems to be quite commonplace, according to [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+delay+of+a+few+days%22).

Comment: I need an attribute